# (HomeKit) How to interact with bridged accessories, compared to normal accessories?

Tags: ios, swift3, homekit

I'm trying to write a simple app to control home kit accessories, and I can interact with normal accessories successfully. But how do I interact with bridged accessories, through the bridge?